# Как ускорить приложение на vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Прочитал много топиков на эту тему, но они все довольно устаревшие, неприменимые к vue-cli.

Проблема в том, что приложение из двух страниц и пары методов весит 4 мегабайта (с любых устройств), грузится более пяти секунд. Вебпак не настраивал, но билд приложения происходит для production. При сборке указано, что gzipped 130 кб, что хорошо, но как gzipped использовать? сервер nginx + express

Comment: Как настроить gzip для nginx можно подсмотреть в гугле. А само приложение можно разбить на чанки (chunks), что тоже легко гуглится

Comment: @фоминаекатерина чанки не особо спасают ситуацию

Comment: Значит нужно больше конкретики. Что у вас занимает так много места, если всего две страницы?